# What happens to a dlopen-ed library if my process crashes?

Tags: dynamic-linking

According to the documentation, `dlclose` decrements a reference counter. But what happens if my process crashes, or if I don't call `dlclose` it before it finishes? Will the reference counter still get decremented, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> According to the documentation, dlclose decrements a reference counter.

This reference counter is inside the dynamic loader and only has meaning *in a particular process*. It has no meaning for the OS (which doesn't care).

> But what happens if my process crashes, or if I don't call dlclose it before it finishes?

Your process "evaporates into thin air". Any reference counts local to that process evaporate with it.

> Will the reference counter still get decremented, and if so, how?

*That* reference count will simply ceases to exist.

However, the OS keeps its own reference counts on any open files and `mmap` mappings established by the process (only indirectly related to `dlopen()`), and the OS *will* decrement *these* counts. If, as a result, any such reference count drops to 0, the corresponding mapping will be removed (by the OS).